# Find MongoDB document with the latest date according to different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

We have data stored in MongoDB by country code. Our document looks like the following,

```
[
    {
        title: '1',
        US: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-09' } // will be fetched
        },
        GB: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-04' }
       }
    },
    {
        title: '2',
        US: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-07' } // will NOT be fetched
        }
    },
    {   
        title: '3',
        US: {
            data: null // will NOT be fetched
        }
    },
    {
        title: '4',
        US: {
            data: null
        }
        GB: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-08' } // will be fetched
        },
        NZ: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-04' }
        }
    },
    {
        title: '5',
        GB: {
            data: null
        },
        NZ: {
            data: { lastReportDate: '2021-09-06' }  // will be fetched
        }
    }
]
```

I want to fetch the titles which have the latest dates according to the countries.
For EX: in the above DB, we have the latest date for US as '2021-09-09', so I want to fetch all the titles which match this date in lastReportDate. For GB, the latest date is '2021-09-08' and for NZ, its '2021-09-06'.


We have around 180 countries in one document and I want to hit the DB minimum times. So can we build a query that can us latest dates for different countries and then query the Database according to that.

Comment: I can query the Database to get the latest date for each country. But I have to do that for every country. So can we form a query such a way that I don't have to hit DB again and again.

Comment: not sure why `title: '4'` is supposed to be returned for `NZ`

Comment: yeah sorry. That was a typo. It was not supposed to be fetched coz the latest date for NZ will be '2021-09-06'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            doc: {
                $objectToArray:"$$ROOT"
            },
            title: "$title"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$doc"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "doc.k": { $nin: [ "_id", "title" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$doc.k",
            maxDate: { $max: "$doc.v.data.lastReportDate" },
            titles: { $push: { date: "$doc.v.data.lastReportDate", title: "$title" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            country: "$_id",
            maxTitles: { $filter: { input: "$titles", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.date", "$maxDate" ] } } }
        }
    }
])
```

The challenge here is that your countries are represented as keys of your document so you need to start with [$obectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator which in conjunction with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) will give you a list of countries with corresponding dates and titles.

Once you have them you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) date and then use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get titles related to max date.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yaVVVHWIVJP)

Comment: thanks for the help. With some modification to this query, I am able to find the exact solution I was looking for.